# How to ease-out border-color on button elements?

Tags: css, button, hover, css-transitions, transition

Here is my [website](https://terrancecorley.github.io/photo_port/) (currently building the mobile version). Here is the [repository](https://github.com/terrancecorley/photo_port) for the site.

```
button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 0.35em;
}

button:hover {
  border-color: #49bf9d;
  transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

I'm having issues with getting the border-color on my button elements to ease-out when hovering off the button element. The ease-in transition works just fine though.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Apologies, I'm still fairly new to Stack Overflow. I've made the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

add the transition property on button instead of hover

CSS

```
button
{
    transition: border 0.2s ease-in-out !important;
}
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
button {
  transition: 0.4s ease-out all;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

button:hover {
  transition: 0.4s ease-in all;
  border-color: red;
}
```

You can also add `-moz-transition` and `-webkit-transition` for older browsers.

Comment: Of course,  you can change the border of the button. This is just as an example. Most likely you forgot the `transition` in the button element itself.